# Domain Configuration for Force.com Site Pages

Tags: custom-domain

I have developed visualforce page and assign this to force.com site. when i run the page it is showing force.com site url so, my client want to use this page with his bussiness domain.For this, I have sent domain url for creating the CName in DNS (GoDaddy) server.

**URL:** `www.abccompany.com.00du00000002323mac.live.siteforce.com`

We have created CName with above URL in Godaddy 48 hours before but still, CName is not activated.

**CName Configuration in GoDaddy:**

**Host:** abccompany

**Points To:**`www.abccompany.com.00du00000002323mac.live.siteforce.com`

**TTL:** 1 Hour

After that, i have tried to create the custom domain in salesforce but i am getting the below exception.

> Error: Salesforce.com can't validate the domain. The CNAME record may
>   still be processing (which can take up to 24 hours), or the domain may
>   not belong to you. Make sure the domain name abcompany uses
>   **abcompany.00du00000002323mac.live.siteforce.com** as its CNAME target and try again later.

Can anybody help me to fix the above issue.

Comment: Your issue is more towards CNAME propagation rather than anything with Salesforce as the error suggests. You should try to get support from GoDaddy (if you can) as what is causing the issue. Take a look at [**this article**](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time-1746) which mentions the several factors considered for a CNAME propagation.

Comment: Looks like your CNAME has `www.abcompany....` but Salesforce is looking for `abcompany...`.

Comment: @Jayant Das: Thank you for your reply. i will review GoDaddy article and let you know if any questions.

Comment: @David Reed: I have tried to create domain with www.abcompany.com but still i am getting the same exception.

Comment: I was suggesting that your `CNAME` is wrong, not your domain name itself.

Comment: you mean CName configuration in GoDaddy is wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's my guess based on the error you're seeing and the configuration details you have provided.